# Find Type of Type parameter

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, c#-2.0

Consider the following:

```
private T getValue<T>(String attr)
{ ... }
```

How do I check to see what Type  is?

I was thinking of:

```
if("" is T) // String
if(1 is T) // Int32
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: This question is more useful than the 'duplicate' because it is asking about just this one thing, whereas the other question has additional baggage affecting the content of the answers.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There's the function `typeof(T)`?

Comment: so if(typeof(T) == Type.GetType("String"))???

Comment: if(typeof(T) == typeof(String)) should be faster

Answer (score 6):

You can use the function `typeof(T)`?

So to check for the string, do

`if(typeof(T) == typeof(string))` // do something

Answer (score 6):

This is almost certainly a flaw in the design of your function if you need to get the type of the generic type parameter; This is *opposite* of “generic”. Hence, use overloading instead.

Other than that, Unsliced has already given the correct answer of determining the type of `T`.

Comment: I need it for debugging purposes.

Comment: You can use it to determine whether the type parameter is a value type like typeof(T).IsValueType.

Comment: @LoBo Sure, but that is *not* what OP was asking, and for most (but not all) purposes you would use a constraint here rather than checking at runtime.

Comment: This is mostly true, but as usual there's an exception: When you need to check if a generic type parameter is numeric. As far as I know this is the only way to validate that.

Comment: "Almost certainly" is a bit strong, especially since you have no idea how this information is going to be used. I have a method to update a fairly complex database structure that could update any number of different columns in a couple different tables, and need to verify that the type of the data passed in matches the type of the column in the database.

Comment: In my case, I'm using an extension method to turn a `Dictionary` into a `DataTable` and am checking to see if the value of the `TKey` and `TValue` are either string, DateTime, or primitive (so we don't get some complex class cluttering things up). So I'm using the `typeof(TKey)` to make sure of the type being passed in, thanks to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are actually 2 methods doing that, if the expected classes derive from the same class or interface or abstract class you can do easly in the Generic Signature

T GetValue() where T : class, this will force whole T Types To Be Reference Types.
Or
T GetValue() where T : IDisposable , this will force whole T Types to implement IDisposable.

for your case typeof(T) will solve your problems, but in this case, make the method not generic.